# Discover device that broadcasts an address on network

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip, broadcast, bridge

I'm very new to network-programming and the only way I know how to discover devices on my local network is to log into my router and manually check the IP and name.

Now  I want to discover a device on my network which is connected through ethernet and I can't find it when I log into my router. The only info I have about the device is that it is **broadcasting a string** of type `ABC-123:<bridge id>` every fifth second to a certain address: `267.1.1.1:4444`.

How can I get the device's IP address to be able to communicate with it through an API? Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't broadcast anything to 267.1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could eventually try to redirect all traffic to your computer with ettercap (https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) and viewing the network traffic with wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/).